# Camel IBM-MQ Durable Subscription to Topic

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Using Camel 2.19.3 ...

I want to read from a TOPIC (IBM-MQ). I set both a 
"durableSubscriptionName" and a client ID.

```
from ("jms:topic:TEST/TOPIC1?durableSubscriptionName=TestSubscription1&clientId=101021&exchangePattern=InOnly")
```

However, the DefaultJmsMessageContainerFactory gives me an error:

```
JMWCC0101: The clientID cannot be null
```

I've tried the same configuration using Spring JmsTemplate directly, and by 
setting the clientId on the connection, and that works.

Do I need to specify a custom "connectionFactory"? Looking at the code for 
DefaultJmsMessageContainerFactory , it looks like it should handle setting 
the clientID to the underlying connection.

Any thoughts on what I should look for?

Comment: is it worth doing clientID=101021 in the url instead of clientId ?

Comment: Doesn't appear to make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for us was to assign a client-id to the Connection Factory, not to the Camel JMS Component, nor to the specific consumer. That level of granularity is all we need in our use-case.

Since we use IBM Liberty, we added a property in server.xml, but there are probably other ways to accomplish the same thing.

```
<jmsConnectionFactory ..... >
    <properties.wmqJms ... clientId="99999"  ... />
</jmsConnectionFactory>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `"com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidClientIDException: JMSCC0111: IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to set a pre-existing client ID on a Connection or JMSContext."` Any idea how can I resolve this?. I have added mqConnectionFactory.setClientID(applicationUniqueName)

Comment: Do you have two or more instances trying to subscribe to a Topic, and they're using the same Client-ID? or setting it to zero?

Comment: Yes. within my spring boot application, I have two subscribers that are listening to two different topics. Am I supposed to also use clientId="someUniqueName" property with both camel URIs of the two subscribers. For now, I am only using durableSubscriptionName="someUniqueName" in both camel URIs of subscribers.

Comment: If the subscription names are unique, there shouldn't be a need beyond that. Check whether you need to set "com.ibm.mq.jms.SupportMQExtensions" https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123580_.htm

Comment: Could you kindly guide me on how to set "com.ibm.mq.jms.SupportMQExtensions" property in a spring boot application? I am using mq-jms-spring-boot-starter dependency and MQConnectionFactory instead of JMSConnectionFactory. Should I put it in application.yml file as "com.ibm.mq.jms.SupportMQExtensions: true" I tried this doesn't work. I tried to [follow](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/373953/when-using-the-mq-classes-for-jms-v80-why-do-i-get/) but am still struggling to set this property at the application configuration level. Thanks